# How to change Future Dynamic into String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following old tutorial, and I get an error on ImageUrl in last line of code:

"Future dynamic can't be assigned to argument type String".

How can I fix that?

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  static FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(
    storageBucket: 'gs://natapp-7d2db/storage/natapp-7d2db.appspot.com/files'
  );

  static StorageReference imageRef = storage.ref().child('cake.png');

  final imageUrl = imageRef.getDownloadURL();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: Container(
        child: Image.network(imageUrl),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: I used

```
child: Image.network(imageUrl.toString)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Container` with Use `FutureBuilder`, as `FutureBuilder` is a widget which used for an async callback which runs on `Future`

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: imageRef.getDownloadURL(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return Container(
                child: Image.network(snapshot.data));
        }

        if (snapshot.hasError) return WidgetThatShowsError();

        // by default show progress because operation is async and we need to wait for result
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
```

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but the future should contain imageRef.getDownloadURL().

Comment: @ZeeshanHussain: Was supposed to update the answer, Anyway thanks for your observation.